# Prove $p ≡ 1 (\bmod 4)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are two integers with GCD 1. Prove that if $p$ is any odd prime which divides $a^2 + b^2$, then $p ≡ 1 (\bmod 4)$.

Hint: We cannot conclude that $a^2 + b^2$ is a prime number, but what if $a$ and
$b$ are odd?

Comment: Idea: Suppose to the contrary that $p$ is of the form $4k+3$.  We are told that $a^2\equiv -b^2\pmod{p}$ Multiply both sides  by the square of the modular inverse $b^{-1}$ of $b$. We get $(ab^{-1})^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. But probably it has already been proved in your course that if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$ then $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ does not have a solution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you help me work it out please?

Comment: Has the fact that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ does not have a solution if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$ been proved in your course? I usually comes quite early.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $p$ is odd, to show that $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, it is enough to show that $p\not\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

We are told that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers such that $p$ divides $a^2+b^2$. Note that $p$ cannot divide $b$. For if $p$ divides $b$, then $p$ divides $b^2$. From the fact that $p$ divides $a^2+b^2$, we conclude that $p$ divides $a^2$, and therefore $p$ divides $a$. This contradicts the fact that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Now from the fact that $p$ does not divide $b$, we conclude that $b$ has a modular inverse modulo $p$. That is, there is a $c$ such that $cb\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Because $p$ divides $a^2+b^2$, we can write $a^2\equiv -b^2\pmod{p}$. Multiply both sides by $c^2$. We get
$$(ca)^2\equiv -(cb)^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}.\tag{1}$$
From (1) we conclude that the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution.  But $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ does not have a solution if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. It follows that $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @Miss I added an answer that clarifies the point in the second-last sentence above.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ 4k\!+\!3=p\mid a^2+b^2\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{a^2\equiv -b^2}\pmod p.\,$ $\ p\!-\!1 = 2(2k\!+\!1)\,$ so by little Fermat

$\ \ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\,\ 1\equiv a^{\large p-1}\equiv (\color{#c00}{a^2})^{\large 2k+1}\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{-b^2})^{\large 2k+1}\equiv - b^{\large p-1}\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid 2\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

Comment: Note $\,a,b\not\equiv 0,\,$ e.g. see the second paragraph of Andre's answer.